# Unable to fetch file from S3 in node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have stored video files in S3 bucket and now i want to show the files to clients through an API. Here is my code for it

```
app.get('/vid', async(req, res) => {

    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: config.awsAccessKey,
        secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretKey,
        region: "ap-south-1"
    });

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();


    var p = req.query.p

    res.attachment(p);

    var options = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: p,

    };

    console.log(p, "name")
    try {
        await s3.getObject(options).
        createReadStream().pipe(res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }


})
```

This is the output I am getting when ther is this file available in S3 bucket -

vid_kdc5stoqnrIjEkL9M.mp4 name

NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.

[image: File in S3 bucket]

Comment: What happens if you print out `BUCKET_NAME` or `p` (this already appears to be in place) to cloudwatch logs? If you replace these values with hard coded strings for the scenario does it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by invalid parameters being passed into the function.

To check for invalid parameters you should double check the strings that are being passed in. For the object check the following:

- Check the value of `p`, ensure it is the exact same name of the full object key.
- Validate that the correct `BUCKET_NAME` is being used
- No trailing characters (such as `/`)
- Perform any necessary decoding before passing parameters in.

If in doubt use logging to output the exact value, also to test the function try testing with hard coded values to validate you can actually retrieve the objects.

For more information take a look at the [How can I troubleshoot the 404 "NoSuchKey" error from Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/) page.

Answer (score 0):

Having certain characters in the bucketname leads to this error.

In your case, there is an underscore. Try renaming the file.

Also refer to this
[S3 Bucket Naming Requirements Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

**Example from Docs:**

The following example bucket names are not valid:

- aws_example_bucket (contains underscores)
- AwsExampleBucket (contains uppercase letters)
- aws-example-bucket- (ends with a hyphen)